# What's the meaning of "?" in {{hero?.name}}

Tags: angular

what does means "?" in the following code:

```
  <span [style.text-decoration]="lineThrough">
     {{prefix}} {{hero?.name}}
  </span>
```

I don't understand the "?" in {{hero?.name}}.
This code is in documentation of Angular:
   https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#custom-events-with-eventemitter

Thanks

Comment: Its called the safe navigation operator. It makes sure that `name` property is only accessed if `hero` is defined (not null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient
>   way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

Read [doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)